# How to handle categorical independent variables in sklearn decision trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I converted all my categorical independent variables from strings to numeric (binary 1's and 0's) using onehotencoder, but when i run a decision tree the algorithm is considering binary categorical variable as continuous.

for e.g. if gender is one of my independent variable, converted male to 1 and female to 0. when i use this in decision tree the node is splitting at 0.5, which makes no sense.

how to convert this numeric continuous to numeric categorical?

Comment: Please provide code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [one hot encode](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-categorical-features) all your categorical variables using either `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` or `pandas.get_dummies`

Comment: did it, but it is still considered as continuous not categorical because the node is splitting at 0.5. how to interpret this 0.5? In R the node splits at either 1 or 0. can we get similar output in sklearn as well

Answer (score 0):

> how to convert this numeric continuous to numeric categorical?

If the result is the same, would you need it?

> for e.g. if gender is one of my independent variable, converted male to 1 and female to 0. when i use this in decision tree the node is splitting at 0.5, which makes no sense.

Maybe I am wrong, but this split makes sense for me.

Let's say we have a decision tree with a split rule that is categorical.
The division would be a binary division, meaning "0" is left and "1" is right (in this case).

Now, how can we optimize this division rule? Instead of searching if a value is "0" or "1", we can use one action to replace these two checks. "0" is left and everything else is right. Now, we can replace this same check from category to a float, <0.5 is left, else is right.

In code, it would be as simple as:

Case 1:

```
if value == "0":
    tree.left()
elif value == "1":
    tree.right()
else:
    pass # if you work with binary, this will never happen, so its useless
```

Case 2:

```
 if value == "0":
     tree.left()
 else:
     tree.right()
```

Case 3:

```
if value < 0.5:
    tree.left()
else:
    tree.right()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 ways to deal with this. You can use

1. Integer encoding (if the categorical variable is ordinal in nature like size etc)
2. One-hot encoding (if the categorical variable is ordinal in nature
   like gender etc)

It seems you have wrongly implemented one-hot encoding for this problem. What you are using is simple integer encoding (or binary encoding, to be more specific). Correctly implemented one-hot encoding ensures that there is no bias in the converted values and the results of performing the machine learning algorithm is not swayed away in favour of a variable just because of its sheer value. You can read more about it [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/).